# How to set up node-gyp correctly and simply on windows ( or avoid it all together )

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

Has anyone got a clear simple path for installing node-gyp correctly.

I am moving away from C# etc to node development - and while I am a newbie with node.js - I am quite disappointed that the major issues I have had have been with a Microsoft related tool.

I need node-gyp ( I think ) to be able to use printers and connect to serial ports & barcode scanners - so I need to be able to get it going consistently or somehow avoid it all together.

I have successfully compiled on 2 different machines.. but it seems that anytime I have to do something on a new machine ( for something like electron or windows server )  - then I seem to spend hours trying to get it going.

The following line is supposed to work:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

And then when adding a package than needs node-gyp - I get the following error

```
The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found.
```

That SDK is installed already ( and tried reinstaling ) . I can't believe how horrible this is to configure and I have read may posts online that don't help.

It seems utterly ridiculous to install packages and complete development environments that are many GBs to get this going.

help!

Answer (score 0):

> I think you have not installed Windows SDK 8.1 correctly. Here is the download link:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

> When the download has finish, restart your computer and adding package ;)

~XeCrafT